# How to find unused bower dependencies

Tags: bower

I am trying to clean my application of unused bower dependencies.

Is there a possibility or a tool to find unused bower dependencies in an application?

Answer (score 1):

Bower downloads the packages and store them in the `bower downloads` directory. It is up to you to refer to these scripts in your application. You can search your application for the specific directory to find out if a script from that directory is ever referred to.

If you are worried about the scripts you are loading and not using any functions from them, there are tools available depending on the technology/framework you use.

If you are worried about the injected dependencies which are hardly ever used in the modules, then you should search for tools specified by the technology/framework.